# NativeScript File Picker Android

Tags: javascript, android, cross-platform, nativescript

How can I pick and attach a file to a form in an Android app?

Comment: Can you please give some more information about what you are trying to achieve and maybe some code samples? What type of files you want to upload?

Comment: @NeliChakarova I simple input type file. Just to select any file or more specifically any single image.

Comment: Ok, actually this is a feature that will come soon. Just stay tuned.

Comment: @NeliChakarova Any progress here? Just came across today, figured something might have changed by now, though didn't find anything in the docs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently this is not possible as confirmed in comments above. I settled for Ionic.